# react-bootstrap-table-next Search is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I recently started using the react-bootstrap-table-next component.  I have not been able to get the search to work.

This is what i have installed:

```
react-bootstrap-table-next 4.0.3
react-bootstrap-table2-paginator 2.1.2
react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit 2.1.3
```

Here's my code:

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';

actionFormat(cell, row, rowIndex) {
        return (<div><span className='fa fa-pencil-square-o' onClick={() => this.props.parentEdit(cell, row, rowIndex)} data-id={cell} title='Edit'></span>
            <span className='fa fa-trash-o' data-id={cell} onClick={() => this.props.parentDelete(cell, row, rowIndex)} title='Delete'></span></div>)
}

render() {    
        if (this.props.isAccount) {
            cols = [{ text: 'Actions', dataField: 'Actions', formatter: this.actionFormat.bind(this) },
            { text: 'Id', dataField: 'Id', sort: true },
            { text: 'Name', dataField: 'Name', sort: true },
            { text: 'User Name', dataField: 'UserName', sort: true },
            { text: 'Created', dataField: 'DateCreatedView', sort: true },
            { text: 'Email Confirmed', dataField: 'EmailConfirmed', sort: true },
            ]
        }
        
        const { SearchBar } = Search;        
        return (
                <Container fluid>
                    <ToolkitProvider
                        keyField="Id"
                        data={this.state.data}
                        columns={cols}
                        search
                        bootstrap4
                    >
                        {
                            props => (
                                <div>
                                    Search:
                                    <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
                                    <BootstrapTable bootstrap4 pagination={paginationFactory(pagingOptions)} width='100vw;'
                                    striped condensed {...props.baseProps}>
                                </BootstrapTable>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                    </ToolkitProvider>
        );
    }
```

Reference the base props in the ToolkitProvider rather then setting the data and column elements in the BootstrapTable element

Comment: I have updated my question with the working solution that was provided here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/1463#issuecomment-684123223